# Jquery tool tip is not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, tooltip

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        }
    });
});

<span title=\"<table class='tooltip'><tr><td class='tooltipqty'>11</td><td class='tooltipqty'>$11-01-13</td></tr></table>\">
Previous Schedule
</span>
```

This is working well with FireFox but with No Error comes and no tooltip comes in IE.
Please help me to what went wrong.

Am using below sources

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.css" />
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"/></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your problem right away, but I did find this for you, it seems like a similar problem. Could you try it out?
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-tooltip-position-fixed